# library search path issues on XCode 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

So when I tried to run my project in my laptop it works fine, but porting it on a different computer gives me:

```
ld: warning: directory '/Developer-3.2.6/MyProject/Twitter+OAuth/Libraries & Headers' following -L not found
ld: library not found for -lOAuth
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer-3.2.6/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

and my library search path is:

> "$(DEVELOPER_DIR)/MyProject/Twitter+OAuth/Libraries & Headers"

How should I resolve this?

Answer (score 5):

Try changing your library search path to escape the spaces and the ampersand (&):

```
$(DEVELOPER_DIR)/MyProject/Twitter+OAuth/Libraries\ \&\ Headers
```

Comment: but then why does this work on my computer and not other macs?

Comment: Not sure really, could be an issue with the project plist being corrupt or having bad data.  You can try clearing the values and then enter them again and see if that helps.